# Cant install MySQL 5.6 with Windows Installer

Tags: mysql

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 with MySQL 5.5.44 and I want to upgrade to 5.6.25.
So I downloaded the [comunity installer](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.6.html) from mysql.com.

When I run the installer, the installer finds my current installation but I cannot upgrade or install 5.6 next to 5.5.

Why isn't it possible to upgrade MySQL server?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem. The installer upgraded me from 5.5.2 to 5.5.43 but it won't ever give me the option to upgrade to 5.6, even though I've downloaded and ran both the 5.6.25 and 5.7.7 installers.

**Solution**: You need to click on "Catalog..." button in the lower right-hand side of the MySQL Installer dialog. Once you've done that, you can update your catalog and the new versions of the server will show up and you can then update.